# Add a css class using to "this" item in a forEach within EJS/node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, foreach, ejs

I've been trying this for hours but I am stumped.

I have a kind of "shopping list" node.js app where you can tick off items as `bought`. I want the bought items to be styled green or smth. It is passing a mongoose obj to the client side along a route.

**Server side:**

```
router.get("/:id", function(req, res){
   //find the list with provided ID
    List.findById(req.params.id).populate("listItems").exec(function(err, foundList){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            //render show template with that list
            res.render("lists/show", {list: foundList});
```

**The `foundList` obj basically has a structure of (not valid code, just so u can get an idea):**

```
List {
   name: String,
   listItems: [{
        text: String,
        bought: Boolean
     }]
```

On the client side I am using a forEach in ejs to loop through the listItems and display a html element for each item:

```
<% list.listItems.forEach(function(listItem){ %>
    <div class="card">
       <div class="card list">
          ..listItem name here
       </div>
    </div>

<% }) %>
```

I want to basically make it so that when an element is checked off and `listItem.bought == true`, the `card list` element is green, and when `lisItem.bought == false`, it's just white.

I've got it working with following code, however if one occurrence of the forEach is `bought = true`, all `.card` elements turn green. I want it so that only the element in question is effected.

```
<% list.listItems.forEach(function(listItem){ %>

            <% if(listItem.bought === true){ %>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                       (".card").css("background-color","green");
                    });
                </script>
             <% } else { %>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        (".card").css("background-color","white");
                    });
                </script>
              <% } %>
       <div class="card">
        <div class="card list">
            ....
```

**Question:** How do I target 1 occurrence of a forEach from server side data in ejs, and add a class/style to it. E.g. if there is 2 items on the list, 1 is bought and one not, one should be green and one white. Currently they both go green.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need jQuery for this. You can just add the background color like this:

```
<% list.listItems.forEach(function (listItem) { %>
    <div class="card" style="background-color: <%= listItem.bought ? 'green' : 'white' %>">
        <div class="card list">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
<% }); %>
```

If you want to use jQuery you probably need do add ids to the cards and use them to change the backgrounds.

Comment: Great, thanks, I added an extra class using the method you suggested.

`<div class="card list <%= listItem.bought ? 'active' : '' %>">`